# Multiple buttons to one embedded code / script

Tags: javascript, html, css, scripting, embedding

I am using embedded script from Formlets on my landing page.

It is basically a button that triggers popup with 'email address' form. Formlets script/code is inserted inside my html code:

```
<section class="description">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.formlets.com/public/assets/scripts/built/delivery/vendor/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
    <a class="button signup" target="_blank" onclick="FormletOpen(&#39;5793b578a9b445952b29bf5a&#39;);" id="5793b578a9b445952b29bf5a" href="http://www.formlets.com/forms/5793b578a9b445952b29bf5a?iframe=true" title="Sign Up for early access">SIGN UP</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.formlets.com/public/assets/scripts/built/delivery/modal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">Formlet("5793b578a9b445952b29bf5a")</script>
</section>
```

What I'd like to have is multiple `<a class="button signup"...>` that would trigger the same action: launch the very same modal. I know copying and pasting that code multiple times won't work well due to 'id' duplicates, so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Can't you use the signup class as a trigger for the function? So when a button with signup is pressed your function will start.

Comment: That would be my guess, but I have no idea how to create that function

Comment: Use the same onclick attribute which triggers the function, don't render the id on the duplicate buttons. Another way would be to let the duplicates trigger a click on the "master" button.

Answer (score 0):

I took Yezzz's advice and that's the solution, I made the  button hidden, and added those divs instead:

```
div class=" button signup" onClick="document.getElementById('5793b578a9b445952b29bf5a').click();" title="Sign Up for early access">SIGN ME UP</div>
```